# Not working h:commandLink (inside rich:dataGrid and h:panelGrid)

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, commandlink

I have a problem with not working h:commandLink. Distinct: when I start my app - everything is good, link is invoke at first time but when a rerender this part of page (using rerendered attribute in another part page) then first click on link do nothing, only reload actual page. But with second click link works fine again. I was reading about this problem but a can't find solution. This is my structure:

```
<rich:panel id="bookTable">
    <h:form>
        <rich:dataGrid style="width:100%;" value="#{bookMenuBean.book_list}"
            var="var" columns="2" elements="10" first="1">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Title"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <rich:panel style="width:100%;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <div id="underHeaderBloc">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:commandLink id="asdv"
                                        actionListener="#{bookTableBean.choiceBook}"
                                        action="#{bookTableBean.navigate}">
                                        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="html.jpg"
                                            id="leftSidebar"></h:graphicImage>
                                        <h:messages />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </h:panelGroup>

        <!--    other panelGroups    -->

                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </div>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </rich:panel>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <rich:dataScroller></rich:dataScroller>
            </f:facet>
        </rich:dataGrid>
    </h:form>
</rich:panel>
```

Comment: You wrote about a rendered attribute, I can't find it in the code above though. Try using the rendered attribute on an h:form component if you used it on a h:panelGroup component.

Comment: Which part (id) are you rerendering?